# When getInnerHtml() method should be used?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In Protractor, there is [`getInnerHtml()` method](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/ee8ec9124477ed20702d6a09a51274864867da1a/lib/element.ts#L10) available on an `ElementFinder` instance:

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));
expect(elm.getInnerHtml()).toEqual("test");
```

I don't see it documented in the [API list](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api) though.

Are there *real world use cases* in testing web applications with selenium when `getInnerHtml()` should be preferred instead of [`getText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText)?

---

I also see [selenium 2.53 has deprecated this method](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/96ed95a97405fa267eea09c4008cda9e7703e84d/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md#change-summary):

> Deprecated `WebElement#getInnerHtml()` and `WebEleemnt#getOuterHtml()`

which, it appears, is the reason why Protractor does not mention it in docs.

Comment: getInnerHTML will return the `HTML` content as well inside a tag but `getText()` will only return the `Text` not the `html code` inside that tag.

Comment: @pArAs thanks for the comment. I am not asking about the differences. I am asking about when it is actually needed to use this method for two main reasons: understand why was it deprecated, [implement this eslint rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/47) and provide more information when one would disable this rule and actually need `getInnerHtml` or `getOuterHtml`.

Comment: Personally, I've never actually used them in a test case.  I only used `getInnerHtml()` or `getOuterHtml()` when I was having issues with locators, and I needed to be absolutely certain that I've finally landed on the correct element

Comment: @Gunderson exactly! That is the only time I've used both `getInnerHtml()` and `getOuterHtml()` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getText()` gets text between the start and end tags of the element while `getInnerHtml()` gets HTML syntax of the element.

Lets have an example HTML and perform both action on `a` :-

```
<a><span>link text</span></a>
```

**`getInnerHtml`** :

- Sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants

  ```
  <span>link text</span>
  ```

This is part of the **DOM Parsing and Serialization** Specification.

**`getText()`** :

- Sets or gets the text between the start and end tags of the object

  ```
  link text
  ```

**Explanation** : If we are using `getText()` it will return only exact text i.e. `link text` while `getInnerHtml()` will return HTML syntax i.e. `<span>link text</span>`.

**This is basically depends on requirements**.

- If requirement is to get text with HTML syntax for the HTML parsing, then `getInnerHtml()` should be used.
- If the requirement is to get only element text between,  then `getText()` should be used.

But some time I personally faced the issue with `getText()` which does not return text of the element due to some designing issue with the HTML or other reason, then also `getAttribute('textContent')` can be used.

In this case `getInnerHtml()` should be used to getting the text but need to perform this action on `span` element instead of `a` element.

**Note**:- `getInnerHtml()` can also be used as `getAttribute("innerHTML")`

Comment: in 3.0 getInnerHtml is being completely removed, what should we use instead?

Comment: @JemiloII You can use `.getAttribute("innerHTML") ` instead