# What is the purpose/history of the getInnerHTML function in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, innerhtml

Chrome appears to have defined `HTMLElement.prototype.getInnerHTML`. I can't find anything about this online. Obviously chrome still provides the `innerHTML` property which works as expected, but I wonder why the `getInnerHTML` method is there. I tested in safari and firefox and it is not present so I'm assuming it's chrome specific. I'm wondering about the purpose/history of this method as opposed to `innerHTML`

[image: picture of chrome devtools showing the getInnerHTML property]

Comment: I can't say this for certain but if I was a betting man I'd bet that this is function was the work of an intern or junior staff member who thought that they were so smart in adding it, and now it has been left in in case anyone out there is using it. Also, I think this question would be better on "Computer Science" on the Stack Exchange as this isn't really a coding issue.

Comment: This typically pops up with Selenium questions e.g. [When getInnerHtml() method should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726764/when-getinnerhtml-method-should-be-used). Looks like GWT also used this method convention. Most people today just use the `innerHTML` property. Might be a carry-over for Java-inspired web frameworks.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yeah I found that question, but that isn't about browser API's. I wonder why it's available in chrome as a property on `HTMLElement`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature seems to have been added
to help serialise DOM including Shadow DOM elements.

This is handy because the usual methods like `HTMLElement.prototype.outerHTML` and `HTMLElement.prototype.innerHTML` don't work with Shadow DOM.

For more information about how this method works, you can check Chromium developer's post:
https://github.com/mfreed7/declarative-shadow-dom?tab=readme-ov-file#serialization

In addition to that, here is a javascript polyfill to support the method in other browsers:
https://gist.github.com/developit/54f3e3d1ce9ed0e5a171044edcd0784f

Here is an issue on the html standard github repo about adding the `getInnerHTML` method: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/8867

Comment: very interesting... This seems like the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a part of Angular's [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) (EOL August 2023) testing framework as well as older versions of [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). Protractor was a wrapper for the Selenium web driver.

In Protractor, the method existed on: `webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getInnerHtml`. This method had a return type of `!webdriver.promise.Promise` which would be resolved with the element's inner HTML. It was a function because the value was not always available right away.

```js
/**
 * Schedules a command to retrieve the inner HTML of this element.
 * @return {!webdriver.promise.Promise.<string>} A promise that will be
 *     resolved with the element's inner HTML.
 */
webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getInnerHtml = function() {
  return this.driver_.executeScript('return arguments[0].innerHTML', this);
};
```

I assume it's in Chrome, because Angular is maintained by Google.

You could always add your own polyfill:

```js
if (HTMLElement.prototype.getInnerHTML === undefined) {
  HTMLElement.prototype.getInnerHTML = function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
  }
}
```